# Saving persistent undo to a single directory, alist format

Tags: association-lists, undo-tree-mode

It looks like this can be achieved by modifying the variable 
undo-tree-history-directory-alist, but I can't figure out how.  I tried a number of lines, the last of which is

```
(setq undo-tree-history-directory-alist ("." ! "~/.emacs.d/undo"))
```

But this returns errors.

Answer (score 15):

You most certainly want:

```
(setq undo-tree-history-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/undo")))
```

The docstring of this variable speaks of an alist aka association list.  These are a list of pairs, where a pair is a cons cell.  The short-hand syntax for a cons cell is `(foo . 1)` whereas the short-hand syntax for returning a list as is would be `'(...)`, both combined result in `'((foo . 1) ...))`.

Comment: This gets rid of the error messages, but I see no undo files in the directory.

Comment: Maybe you need to pass that path through `expand-file-name ()` first.

Answer (score 5):

Here's the answer from @wasamasa, but in the use-package format:

```
(use-package undo-tree
  :defer t
  :diminish undo-tree-mode
  :init (global-undo-tree-mode)
  :custom
  (undo-tree-visualizer-diff t)
  (undo-tree-history-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/undo")))
  (undo-tree-visualizer-timestamps t))
```

This worked for me as is, no file expansion needed.

Comment: `use-package`'s `:init` section code runs _before_ the package is loaded.  The function `global-undo-tree-mode` is defined in `undo-tree.el`.  Wouldn't the call fail?

Answer (score 1):

I store the directory path in a variable and use it also to create the directory if it doesn't exist:

```lisp
  (defvar --undo-history-directory (concat user-emacs-directory "undos/")
    "Directory to save undo history files.")
  (unless (file-exists-p --undo-history-directory)
    (make-directory --undo-history-directory t))
  ;; stop littering with *.~undo-tree~ files everywhere
  (setq undo-tree-history-directory-alist `(("." . ,--undo-history-directory)))
```

While this was inspired from the other answers, I'm putting it here since I stumbled around the quoting since `--undo-history-directory` is a variable and not a string literal.

For those interested, we're using [the backquote construct](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Backquote.html) to selectively evaluate elements in a list.